# Android - Get Host isn't returning consitently

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-webview

I have my own `MyWebViewClient` that extends `WebViewClient` for my `webView` in my app. Instead of making complicated navigation bars that may not be supported on all models, I have implemented my own `USERAGENT` string on the webview and using the back end of the website, I show a different link on the page. I have made two links that are supposed to fire events when clicked. Here is the function I am using to accomplish this

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if (request.getUrl().getHost().equals("close.app")) {
            clearCookiesAndCache();
            return false;
        }
        if (request.getUrl().getHost().equals("showsettings.app")) {
            openSettingsMenu();
            return true;
        }
        if (request.getUrl().getHost().equals(SERVER_URL)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

If the user visits the `SERVER_URL` string, which is the domain my webView loads, then we load the new page in the webView. If they click OUTSIDE the web address (`example.com`), such as `notexample.com`, then we start a new intent to open the external link in chrome or some other browser.

This works GREAT in my android environment inside Android Studio. When I added this to my live testing device however, clicking the links is trying to load them as a page instead of firing the showSettings event or logging them out like it does in my studio environment.

What am I doing wrong here that it's not getting the proper host string on all devices? Just in-case, here is my showSettings function, which again does fire properly in the Studio Environment (Nexus 5, and Google Pixel 2), my test device is a Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge btw

```
public void openSettingsMenu() {
    Log.e(TAG, "They requested the settings menu");
    isSettingsOpen = true;
    startActivity(new Intent(Browser.this, appSettings.class));
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. Apparently on older versions you need to override the String Url instead of webresourcerequest. Once I converted to the string version, it started to work. I am unsure which version is deprecated, so I will use this one since it seems to be working now. Here is the updated working code!

```
   @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("close.app")) {
            clearCookiesAndCache();
            return true;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("showsettings.app")) {
            openSettingsMenu();
            return true;
        }
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals(SERVER_URL)) {
            return false;
        }
        final Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```